# SocketTimeout Exception on Jedis del operation

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm regularly getting SocketTimeout Exception on del operation on redis server using Jedis. It's only 1% of all the delete operations done.

Exception:-

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:195) ~[jedis-2.x.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40) ~[jedis-2.x.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:141) ~[jedis-2.x.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205) ~[jedis-2.x.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297) ~[jedis-2.x.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:222) ~[jedis-2.x.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.del(Jedis.java:145) ~[jedis-2.x.jar:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.ShardedJedis.del(ShardedJedis.java:252) ~[jedis-2.x.jar:?]
```

I checked my shared pool configuration and it is enough to handle the traffic. I did a client list on the server and do not see any client with age over 180 sec. Any broken resource is dropped from the pool.

**What could be the issue here and how can I investigate this further?**

Comment: You could start by ruling out errors in redis by checking it's log. Usually located at `/var/log/redis/redis-server.log` but will obviously vary.

Comment: I checked the redis log, but did not find anything unusual there. I could only see periodic writes to AOF but no errors or exceptions.

Comment: Do you see those DEL operations in the slowlog?

Comment: Are you doing any blocking operation? And what exactly is `jedis-2.x`?